# How to make Multiple Forms more reliable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, design-patterns

I am looking for a neat solutions for the multiple Forms.

Have a look at the example screenshot:

[image]

There are three networks in the dropdown, AT&T, Verizon Wireless and T-Mobile.

I've selected 'AT&T' from the dropdown list and then 'Sale Type' radios appear. 
T-Mobile network may have **same** Sale Type as 'AT&T' network but two extras Sale Type.

Majority of the text boxes from all the Sale Type are the same. For example:

Consumers will have 20 Fields and Business have 27 Fields (Extras Fields).  Sim-Only will have less fields - 15 Fields (A few removed and new fields).

What is a good solution implement like this and DRY principle?

I have used jQuery with a lot of **$('.name').hide(); $('.name').hide();** but it get real messy.  Example:

```
$(".at&t_consumer_radio").click(function(){
       showSaleType("at&t_consumer");
});

function showSaleType(type) {
        if (type == "at&t_consumer") { 
          $('.name').hide(); 
          $('.name').hide(); and so on..
     } 
}
```

When completing the form, then I use PHP to validate it.

Comment: Why do you have multiple $('.name').hide(); calls? One call will hide all element with a class of "name".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GvGoldmedal/hct4V/

Comment: @MattMoore Like I said majority of fields from each Sale Type are the same. I don't want to hide all the fields. I am looking for DRY principle solution. More fields and Sale Type could expand in the future.

Comment: Sorry you're not being specific enough. Update your question with your html code and all your JS so we can get a better handle on what you want.

Comment: I've got a solution for you, I'm writing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GvGoldmedal/FxEGP/

Your best bet is to create the following class tags:

.att, .verizon. , .tmobile, .consumer, .business, .sim

Then you can tag the fields based on when they need to be hidden. If a field is used for verison then it'd get a verizon class. If a field is bussiness type then it'd get the business class. Also add the "hide" class to any field that isn't ALWAYS showing.

```
Some Field:
<input type="text" class=" hide verizon att consumer" />

Another Field
<input type="text" class = " hide att business" />
```

Make sure to label every field. Also make sure your radio buttons and the options in your select have values that match the classes. And give your select and radio button a class of 'option', like so:
    
      att
       verizon
      tmobile

```
<input type='radio' name='sale_type' class='option' value="business" />
<input type='radio' name='sale_type' class='option' value="consumer" />
<input type='radio' name='sale_type' class='option' value="consumer" />
```

.. and so on

Now for the Jquery:

```
//selectId is the ID of your select 
// myform is the id of your form



$(".option").change(function()
{   
     // get the value of our select and option
     carrier =  $('#selectId option:selected').val();
     sale_type = $('input[name=sale_type]:checked').val();

    // Hide all fields that don't always show up.
     $(".hide").hide();

    //Show all fields that match our carrier and sale type

    $(".hide").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(carrier) && $(this).hasClass(sale_type))
        {            
            $(this).show();
        }    
    });
});
```

There you have it. Anytime a new option is selected all the fields that aren't part of the form all the time will be hidden and the ones matching your carrier and sale type will then be shown. It will happen almost immediately and the user won't be able to tell the different. You can do some fading to make it look more smooth if you want. Also, if a field is visible for both verizon and att then just add both classes to that input. Let me know if you have any questions.

I'll try and get a Fiddle up showing exactly how to do it.

Comment: Similar idea to me, you've just put a bit more effort into explaining it. I was trying to be precise about it and failed :(.

Comment: Eh it's a lot to explain. You nailed the exact idea I had. Seems like the only way to do it with the DRY principle.

Comment: That is really good idea and thank you! I understood your concept well. There is one issue.. Let say after submit a form and there is an error (validation).. It will then return/redirect back to the Form page but carrier and sale type you have selected before will be selected this time..

Comment: Accept the answer if this worked out for you. To solve your validation issue, validate the form before its submitted with jquery.. if it doesn't validate, stop the form from submitting. Your values will be retained. Does that make sense?

Comment: sorry, I meant "will NOT be selected this time".. I will be using PHP Validation though

Comment: Thanks for jsfiddle example :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck with it.

Comment: Do you think this solution is better than ajax? For example When you select network and sale type and then use ajax to show specific form.

Comment: This is better than ajax in this situation, IMO. Also, there was some errors with my Fiddle that were bringing back too much information. I've corrected the problem. You can use the same link to see the update code.

Answer (score 1):

Hide all the fields that are only shown for specific choices e.g Business or sim free.

Like so

```
<input type="text" class="standard" />
<input type="text" class="business" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" class="simOnly" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" class="standard" />
<input type="text" class="business simOnly" style="display:none" />
```

Not sure i'm explaining this that well. :(

Then use jquery to just show the business ones if that option is chosen

```
$("#businessRadio").click(function(){          
    $('.business').show();   
});
```

This way you aren't showing and hiding everything, just those inputs specific to each sale type